# Header of grid stays after removal of all data of grid laravel

Tags: ajax, laravel, html-table, controller

I have a design of grid in controller that displays me all data of selected check boxes.
This grid gets appended to a span through ajax. 
While performing a delete request, one by one my data in grid gets deleted, 
but the grid header stays as it is.

This is my design of grid in controller:

```
 $res_div = '';
$res_div.='<table width="100%" border="0"  class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">';
        $res_div.='<tr>
                   <th width="100%">SublawId</th>
                   <th width="100%">Sublawname</th>
                   <th width="100%">View</th>
                   <th width="100%">Update</th>
                   </tr>';
        foreach ($law as $sublaw)
        {
            $law_details = DB::table('tbl_law_sub_master')->where('id', $sublaw->id)->select('*')->first();
            $res_div.='<tr>
                       <td>
                       <strong>'.$law_details->lms_id.'</strong>
                       </td>
                       <td>
                       <strong>('.$law_details->sub_law_name.')</strong>
                       </td>
                       <td align="center">
                       <input type="checkbox" id="cb1" onclick="ts(this)" class="cb1" name="viewsub_'.$sublaw->id.'">
                       </td>
                       <td align="center">
                       <input type="checkbox" id="cb1" onclick="ts(this)" class="cb1" name="updatesub_'.$sublaw->id.'">
                        </td>
                        </tr>';
        }
        $res_div.='</table>';
        $data=array(
            'res_div'=>$res_div,
            'law'=>$law
        );    
        return json_encode($data);
```

my ajax request on blade:

```
$.ajax({
      url: "{{ URL::to('staff/staffpostsublawsdata') }}?sub_law_id="+sublaw_ids.join(),
      type: 'POST',
      dataType: "json",
      data: formData,
      async: false,
      cache: false,
      contentType: false,
      processData: false,
      success: function (returndata) {
      var res_sublaw_content=returndata.res_div;
      var data = document.getElementById("append_sublaw_grid").innerHTML = "";                                            $('#append_sublaw_grid').append(res_sublaw_content);
      return false;
       }
});
```

On deletion all data gets deleted one by one from grid, but its header stays..

A screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everytime you remove a row u can count the number of rows left using

```
var rowCount = $('.table tbody tr').length;
```

if `rowcount` goes to 0 then just hide the table using

`$('.table').hide()`

**Working example:**

Put this code in the function where you delete the rows

```
var rowCount = $('.table tbody tr').length;
if( rowcount == 0){
     $('.table').hide();
}
```